# Code migration line chart from d3 v3 to v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am very new to d3 so sorry if this is obvious but I am migrating a line chart from d3.js v3 to v4 and am getting the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

I had look at previously asked question and they say that path[0][0] is OK to use instead of path.node()

This the part of the code that is throwing the error

```
var totalLength = [path[0][0].getTotalLength() , path[0].getTotalLength()] ;
console.log(totalLength);
```

Here is the the code in its entirety but i think the problem is to do with the date format i choose at the beginning:

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 100, left: 500},
    width = 1000 //- margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
/* var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse; */

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
 //   .ticks(8)
    .innerTickSize(2)
    .outerTickSize(2)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b")); // tickFormat

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return d ;})
    .ticks(5)
    .innerTickSize(5)
    .outerTickSize(2)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.accdnt); });


var svg = d3.select("#cell3").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[2]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  });

  var year = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, accdnt: +d[name]};
      })
    };
  });


  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

  y.domain([
            0,d3.max(year, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.accdnt; }); })
        ]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);


  svg.append("line")
        .attr(
        {
            "class":"horizontalGrid",
            "x1" : 0,
            "x2" : width,
            "y1" : y(0),
            "y2" : y(0),
            "fill" : "none",
            "shape-rendering" : "crispEdges",
            "stroke" : "black",
            "stroke-width" : "1px",
            "stroke-dasharray": ("3, 3")
        });

  var company = svg.selectAll(".company")
      .data(year)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "company");



  var path = svg.selectAll(".company").append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { if (d.name == "2013") 
                                        {return "rgb(000,255,000)"}
                                    if (d.name == "2014") 
                                        {return "rgb(045,255,251)"}
                                    if (d.name == "2015") 
                                        {return "rgb(128,125,044)"}
                                      else {return "#000";}
                                         });




var totalLength = [path[0][0].getTotalLength(), path[0][1].getTotalLength()];

console.log(totalLength);


   d3.select(path[0][0])
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength[0] + " " + totalLength[0] ) 
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength[0])
      .transition()
        .duration(2500)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

   d3.select(path[0][1])
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength[1] + " " + totalLength[1] )
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength[1])
      .transition()
        .duration(2500)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

   d3.select(path[0][2])
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength[1] + " " + totalLength[1] )
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength[1])
      .transition()
        .duration(2500)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);  

});
```

Comment: I'm updating a number of components from D3 v3.5.17 -> v4.4.0 and I pretty much have [this migration guide](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md) open in a tab at all times :)

Answer (score 1):

If you try that code referencing D3 v4.x, **several** parts will throw an error, not only the one you mentioned. Those are wrong:

- d3.time.format
- d3.time.scale()
- d3.scale.linear()
- d3.scale.category10()
- d3.svg.axis()
- d3.svg.line()
- line.interpolate

Explaining just the part you mentioned (*"This the part of the code that is throwing the error"*):

According to D3 4.x API,

> Selections no longer subclass Array using prototype chain injection; they are now plain objects, improving performance.

So, in D3 version 4.x, selections are objects. That's why `path[0][0]` doesn't work anymore.

If you console.log your selection, you're gonna see something like this:

```
Selection {_groups: Array[1], _parents: Array[1]}
```

Thus, you have to use `path.nodes()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try looking at the value of path[0][0] console.log(path)